# unconverted data remains python strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert strings to datetime in python, but I am getting an error "unconverted data remains: 11". The strings I am dealing with have a form like "Dec\xa031 2011". I think the unicode character is causing a problem. I have tried splitting on \xa0 which gives me ['Dec', '31 2011'], then joining. I have also tried replacing by re with re.sub('\xa0', '', dateStr). Neither has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for your example:

```
import datetime
s = "Dec\xa031 2011"
datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%b\xa0%d %Y")
```

Outputs:

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @user137717 You're welcome. You should accept the answer and next time please detail what you have tried.